# How to upload image in Summernote Editor (AngularJs version)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, summernote

Can anyone tell me how to upload image in summernote editor (angularJs v.)?
My Code:

```js
$scope.imageUpload = function(files) {
  uploadEditorImage(files);
};

function uploadEditorImage(files) {
  if (files != null) {
       Upload.upload({
          url: ROUTES.RESOURCESUPLOADFILE,
          file: files
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         var uploaded_file_name = data.file_name,
         file_location = '/assets/uploads/'+uploaded_file_name;
         $scope.editor.summernote('editor.insertImage', uploaded_file_name);
       });
  }
};
```

```html
   

 <summernote editor="editor" editable="editable" on-image-upload="imageUpload(files)"  ng-model="lessonFormEditData.description" ></summernote>
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'summernote' of undefined
```

Also "editable" parameter return undefined:

```
$scope.imageUpload = function(files) {
          console.log($scope.editable); // undefined
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code like above in after success.

```
var uploaded_file_name = data.file_name;
var file_path = '/assets/uploads/'+uploaded_file_name;
var editor = $.summernote.eventHandler.getModule();
editor.insertImage(vm.editable, file_path, uploaded_file_name);
```